# How do I write a live search function for my dynamically generated table?

Tags: javascript, arrays, datatables, indexof, lastindexof

I have a script that generates a dynamic table from values stored in an array. I would like to write a live **search** function `searchByNumber()`. How do I write a live **search** function based on values in the **Amount**  and **Time** column that would dynamically filter the exiting table?

Find below an image to illustrate what a generated table would look like:

[image: An image of the dynamically generated table]

Again, **NOTE** that the search values will be based on the values in the **Amount** and **Time** columns as seen in the image above.

Find below the script which shows the array configuration, and how the dynamic table is generated:

```
var array = [{
  TransactionTime: "August 2, 2019 4:34 PM"
  amount: "100"
  payersNumber: "0705357658"
  paymentStatus: "Success! payment received."
  statusIcon: "<i class='fas fa-check-circle colorBlue'></i> <a 
  href='#'>"
  transactionNumber: "ATPid_40a31c1aad441a3de2f70a17669e651a"
  waitersName: "John.P"
},
{
  TransactionTime: "August 1, 2019 2:34 AM"
  amount: "150"
  payersNumber: "0705357658"
  paymentStatus: "Failed! payment not received."
  statusIcon: "<i class='fas fa-check-circle colorRed'></i> <a 
  href='#'>"
  transactionNumber: "ATPid_40a31c1aad441a3de2f70a17669e651a"
  waitersName: "Maggie.A"
}];

table = document.getElementById("table");

var currentTransaction;
var keys = ["statusIcon", "amount", "TransactionTime"];
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
console.log("Number of transactions: " + array.length);
var newRow = table.insertRow(table.length);

  currentTransaction = array[i];
  for (var b = 0; b < keys.length; b++) {
    var cell = newRow.insertCell(b);
    cell.innerText = currentTransaction[keys[b]];
  }
}
```

Following is the HTML code showing the table, also notice the search field:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/v4-shims.css">

<form id="Searchform" class="Search form delay-4.9s">
  <input id="searchPhoneNumber" type="text" onkeyup="searchByNumber()">     
</form>     


<table id="table" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Status</th>
    <th>Amount</th>
    <th>Time</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

How do I write a live search function **searchByNumber()** to filter the already generated table?

Looking forward to your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is solution using pure javascript excluding the first row which is header.

```js
var array = [{
  TransactionTime: "August 2, 2019 4:34 PM",
  amount: "100",
  payersNumber: "0705357658",
  paymentStatus: "Success! payment received.",
  statusIcon: "<i class='fas fa-check-circle colorBlue'></i> <a ,href='#'>",
  transactionNumber: "ATPid_40a31c1aad441a3de2f70a17669e651a",
  waitersName: "John.P",
},
{
  TransactionTime: "August 1, 2019 2:34 AM",
  amount: "150",
  payersNumber: "0705357658",
  paymentStatus: "Failed! payment not received.",
  statusIcon: "<i class='fas fa-check-circle colorRed'></i> <a ,href='#'>",
  transactionNumber: "ATPid_40a31c1aad441a3de2f70a17669e651a",
  waitersName: "Maggie.A",
}];


table = document.getElementById("table");

var currentTransaction;
var keys = ["statusIcon", "amount", "TransactionTime"];
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  console.log("Number of transactions: " + array.length);
  var newRow = table.insertRow(table.length);
  currentTransaction = array[i];
  for (var b = 0; b < keys.length; b++) {
    var cell = newRow.insertCell(b);
    cell.innerText = currentTransaction[keys[b]];
  }
}

function searchByNumber(){
  var input = document.getElementById("searchPhoneNumber");
  var table = document.getElementById("table");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  var tr = document.getElementById("table").getElementsByTagName('tr');
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td") ; 
    for(j=0 ; j<td.length ; j++)
    {
      let tdata = td[j] ;
      if (tdata) {
        if (tdata.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
          tr[i].style.display = "";
          break ; 
        } else {
          tr[i].style.display = "none";
        }
      } 
    }
  }


}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/v4-shims.css">

<form id="Searchform" class="Search form delay-4.9s">
  <input id="searchPhoneNumber" type="text" onkeyup="searchByNumber()">     
</form>     


<table id="table" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Status</th>
    <th>Amount</th>
    <th>Time</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You can short this `document.getElementById("table").getElementsByTagName('tr')` with `table.getElementsByTagName('tr')` and `filter = input.value.toUpperCase()` i think you should add `var` there.